# 'No numeric types to aggregate' for Pandsas pivot_table

Tags: pandas, seaborn, pivot-table, heatmap

I have a dataframe that looks like this (pls click the link to download it):

[Dataframe sample](https://github.com/StefanoPuccini/Stack-Overflow/blob/963ba7bd735e2a21860630de7cbad8338836d40a/merge_3f.csv)

What I'd like to do is creating a sort of heatmap where the is_commodity value is highlighted when == 1.

Final result should be something like this:

[image]

What I've tried so far (I shoulnd't be that far from the solution) is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

pivot_ind=pd.pivot_table(merge_3f,index=['family','SF_type'],values=['is_commodity'],columns= 
['SIC'])
pivot_ind

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(20,10))

colormap = sns.color_palette("Greens")

sns.heatmap(pivot_ind.query('SF_type=="SMB"'), annot=False, linewidths=0.5, cmap= colormap, 
cbar=False, ax=ax1)
sns.heatmap(pivot_ind.query('SF_type=="CORP"'), annot=False, linewidths=0.5, cmap= colormap, 
cbar=False, ax=ax2, yticklabels=False)

#repeat xticks for each plot
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=75)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=75)

#remove axis titles
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax2.set_xlabel('')

ax1.set_title('SMB')
ax2.set_title('CORP')
```

Unfortunately I get the 'No numeric types to aggregate' and I don't know how  to solve it.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who will help me.

Stefano

Comment: How do you read the dataframe? When I execute he code sample, i get a output graph

Comment: Same with me, code runs fine in Jupyter and outputs a heatmap

Comment: Well, that's strange :(
The dataframe I've posted it's a sample from a bigger dataframe but it's just a simple query:

`merge_3f=merge_2f.query('product_basket=="HYG" & industry_group == "Business" & family != "HYGIENE & CLEANING"')`

so nothing fancy...how is that possible that I get a different output (error)?

Comment: Hye guys, maybe I got that. somehow I think that the is_commodity variable was not stored as integer but as an object. Using: `merge_3f = merge_3f.astype({"is_commodity":int})`  did the trick